# How do I generate an XML file with the proper CGI header in pylons?

Tags: xml, cgi, pylons

I'm trying to write a simple pylons action to generate some xml.  Here's the gist, with toy xml:

```
class HelloController(BaseController):
    def index(self):
        my_xml = etree.Element("root")
        etree.SubElement(root, "child1")
        etree.SubElement(root, "child2")
        etree.SubElement(root, "child3")

        return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'+etree.tostring( my_xml, pretty_print=True )
```

But when I display this in firefox, it's a garbled mess--firefox doesn't try to parse it as xml.

The problem is (I think) that I'm not attaching the proper CGI header, but I can't find any documentation on how to do that in pylons.  What should I do?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return response HTTP header that declares content type of the response. In a Pylons controller you use global `pylons.response` (which is an instance of [webob.Response](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/thirdparty/webob/#webob.Response)) object for that.

At the imports section add:

```
from pylons import response
```

Somewhere in your controller action add:

```
response.content_type = "text/xml"
```